# why does angularJS treat spaces as empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

In angularJS, I have a input field bind with ng-model, have something show if input is not empty.

```
<input id="name" type="text" ng-model="typeSignature" placeholder="Type your name here">
<div ng-show="typeSignature==''"> Something</div>
```

When I press space key, the boolean of `typeSignature==''` is still true. However, in jQuery the boolean `$('#name').val() == ''` will be false if I have pressed space.

Why is angularJS treating space differently? How can I make jQuery `val()` function consistent with anguLarJS, namely treating space as empty as well?

Comment: Can you show your `name()` function? Presumably it mutates `typeSignature`?

Comment: Try to find a way to implement your solution in Angular without using jQuery -- it's probably possible, and more reliable than mixing two frameworks.

Comment: `$.trim($("#name").val())`

Comment: Your `ng-model` is a function? Dont know if this is even possible. Even if: When the `name()`-function doenst set the `typeSignatur`-variable in the scope, it wont work. When you replace `name()` with `typeSignature` it should work

Comment: @Blazemonger I am not mixing the frameworks, i need prepare two sets of solutions to support old browser that angularJS doesnt support

Comment: @Fuzzyma sorry it was a mistake. My ng-model is just normal angular model

Comment: Its truthy check, use === instead of == [truth-equality-and-javascript](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default behavior of angular is to trim the model value.
So, if you want to listen to space in model you can set the flag ng-trim="false"

```
<input ng-model="test" ng-trim="false"/>
```

Comment: This explains it well. Thanks

Comment: If it helped in solving your problem please do accept the answer :) ;)

Comment: [Documentation for text inputs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)